# Magento media on Google cloud

Tags: extensions, cloud, google

I am new to magento. I need to stored my media files on google cloud. I have search for an extension but not found anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it will work.

1. Upload images to google cloud and point your CNAME (gcdn.example.com) to google cloud end point.
2. Go to system > configuration > web > unsecure/secure.
3. Change your media url to gcdn.example.com/media.

Comment: correct. but he need to move new product image when admin upload it from admin

Comment: That's pretty easy. All you have to do it do a "put" request from your current drive to google cloud using .key file of gcdn. That can be done for incremental media files via NFS.

Comment: but my requirement is that images should automatically get uploaded to GCS. Is there any plugin/extension available which can do this ?